# Inserting "missing records" in a CTE with dates as a key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

I have a CTE with the following structure

```
ITEM,   DATE,       QUANTITY,   EXTRA
AAAA    01-07-2015  100         20
AAAA    04-07-2015  100         13
AAAA    07-07-2015  100         16
AAAA    09-07-2015  100         23
.
.
.
AAAA    31-07-2015  100         30
```

Basically, what I want to do is get the records out with the 'missing dates' in there and the EXTRA field containing the EXTRA from the previous record (as below)

```
ITEM,   DATE,       QUANTITY,   EXTRA
AAAA    01-07-2015  100         20
AAAA    02-07-2015  0           20
AAAA    03-07-2015  0           20
AAAA    04-07-2015  100         13
AAAA    05-07-2015  0           13
AAAA    06-07-2015  0           13
AAAA    07-07-2015  100         16
AAAA    08-07-2015  0           16
AAAA    09-07-2015  100         23
.
.
.
AAAA    31-07-2015  100         30
```

I could just insert the records manually using a mix of LAG and a temp table containing the full list of valid dates + MERGE.  However, this CTE is just used for one-time checking then disposed. Is there a better way?

Comment: Use a **calendar** table and to an outer join against that - this will return all dates in the range you specify, with (or without) data from the other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
;with tbl as (
    --your data....
),
max_min_val as (
  select max(date) as max_date, min(date) as min_date from tbl
),
all_date AS (
    SELECT min_date as DateColumn 
    from max_min_val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,DateColumn)
    FROM all_date, max_min_val
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,DateColumn) <= max_date
)
select 
    coalesce(t.item, (select top 1 tt.item from tbl tt where tt.date < x.DateColumn order by tt.date desc)) as item,
    x.DateColumn as date, 
    coalesce(t.QUANTITY, 0) as QUANTITY,
    coalesce(t.EXTRA, (select top 1 tt.EXTRA from tbl tt where tt.date < x.DateColumn order by tt.date desc)) as EXTRA
from all_date x
left join
tbl t on t.date = x.DateColumn
```

1. Here `all_date` will have all `date` between `min and max date in tbl`.
2. Left join `all_date` will give all the dates
3. `coalesce(t.QUANTITY, 0) as QUANTITY` will give `t.QUANTITY` if `not null` else `0`
4. `EXTRA` and `item` will give previous rows data from `CTE tbl` based on `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

I made a `CTE` representing your data (not considering the `ITEM` since it is not relevant in the example).

With the following two `CTE`s I'm searching for the missing dates between the min and max of the available `data` using a `recursive query`.

Next, you need to join the right `data` to the available `dates`. The key is to get the row with the max `date` from `data`, as long as `data.date` is less equal `dates.date`.

Lastly, my interpretation based on the example is that you want to inherit `extra`, but not `quantity`. Hence the `case`-statement in the `select`.

```
with data as (
    select cast('2015-07-01' as date) date, 100 quantity, 20 extra union all
    select cast('2015-07-04' as date) date, 100 quantity, 13 extra union all
    select cast('2015-07-07' as date) date, 100 quantity, 16 extra union all
    select cast('2015-07-09' as date) date, 100 quantity, 23 extra
)

, maxDate as (
    select MAX(date) date
    from data
)

, dates as (
    select date
    from data

    union all

    select DATEADD(day,1,date) date
    from dates
    where DATEADD(day,1,date) not in (select date from data)
        and DATEADD(day,1,date) < (select date from maxDate)
)

select dates.date
, case dates.date when data.date then data.quantity else 0 end quantity
, data.extra
from dates
join data on data.date = (select max(date) from data where data.date <= dates.date)
order by 1
```